# Can I make a flash file I developed to run on Androis / IOS?

Tags: android, ios, flash, actionscript

I've created a simple game using ActionScript 3.0 and Adobe Flash CS5.
Is there any way to run this creation on Android / Apple IOS ?
(Even if so, I still have no Idea how to work with "touch" interfaces, just want to know if such thing is possible first.)

Comment: Did you try googling the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! You can use Adobe AIR to package and export the Flash file.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ff6.html

Answer (score 0):

You could port the code to [Haxe](http://haxe.org), which is really easy since the languages (AS3 and Haxe) are almost identical, and just compile it natively for both android and IOS. I think that's better than adobe air... I feel like air is slow.